# TypeScript: Type check for array or number

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to achieve an object type with a fixed property whose value is either an array or a number.

```
type Gt = {$gt: Array<any> | number}

export default (expression: Array<any> | number): Gt => {
  if (Array.isArray(expression)) {
    let gt: Gt = {$gt: []}

    const [key, value] = expression
    gt.$gt.push(key, value)

    return gt
  } else {
    return {$gt: expression}
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> src/operators/gt.ts (15,12): Property 'push' does not exist on type
>   'number | any[]'.

When I change it to `type Gt = {$gt: any}` it works fine. I don't understand why.

Comment: Since $gt can be a number and numbers do not have push yo7 get that error.

Comment: That's why I do the check: `if (Array.isArray(expression))`. Isn't that enough for TypeScript? What else could I do?

Comment: The `isArray` check is being done on `expression` not on `gt.$gt`, which is the thing that you are calling `push` on.

Comment: Btw you can cast an element by adding `<type>` in front of it. Where type of course is the type of you want to cast to

Comment: Thank you for this. But this isn't applicable in this case, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding TypeScript's understanding of the `gt` object you are creating when you explicitly set its type to `Gt`.

Try changing the line

```
let gt: Gt = {$gt: []}
```

to

```
let gt = {$gt: []}
```

That explicit typing overrides TypeScript knowing that `$gt` in this case is an array and instead tells it that it's `Array<any> | number` even though you've explicitly made it an array.

Doing this change will not conflict with the return type of the function, since the resulting object still conforms to the `Gt` type.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the line

```
let gt: Gt = {$gt: []}
```

Yes, you know that `gt.$gt` contains an array, but, by casting `{$gt: []}` to `Gt`, the TypeScript compiler loses that information, so, when you later do `gt.$gt`, it only knows that `gt` is of type `Gt`, and so `$gt` can contain either an array or a number. This might be stupid, but the compiler can't keep track, along with type information, the previous types of a value.

That's why you can't do

```
const p : string = [];
```

but if works if you write

```
const p: string = [] as any;
```

because `[]` can be assigned to `any`, and `any` can be assigned to anything.

You don't need to declare `gt` as being `Gt`, the type `{$gt: Array<any>}` can be assigned to `Gt`, so you should write the function this way:

```
(expression: Array<any> | number): Gt => {
  if (Array.isArray(expression)) {
    let gt = {$gt: []}

    const [key, value] = expression
    gt.$gt.push(key, value)

    return gt
  } else {
    return {$gt: expression}
  }
}
```